# How to remove static linking from Firedac SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe7, firedac

I'm currently using Delphi XE7 Update 1 with FIREDAC actually it seems that FireDac links statically the sqlite3.dll but it uses an old version , what i want to do dynamcally link the newest library to my application , I have followed that link [Connect_to_SQLite_database_(FireDAC)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Connect_to_SQLite_database_(FireDAC)) which guide you how to do it but it fails it stills showing "Static linking" even if I does like mentioned, any help will be much appreciated . 
[image]

Comment: It is not enough to edit `FireDAC.inc`. What Embarcadero's documentation does not tell you is that after you edit the file, you have to recompile the FireDAC source code so your edits take effect. Whether or not you have the FireDAC source code depends on which edition of Delphi you have installed. It is not included in the Trial, Starter, or Pro edition.

Comment: So how can I link to the librrary dynamically , do i have to change the source !!!

Comment: `FireDAC.inc` is part of the FireDAC source code. After editing `FireDAC.inc`, you have to *recompile* FireDAC itself. If you cannot do that, then you cannot link dynamically.

Comment: It seems that i can adding the FireDac source folder to the library path and modifying "FireDac.inc" will solve the problem ^^ thanks for the tip